# Symfony 6.4 import bootstrap icons wit AssetMapper

Tags: symfony, symfony-assetmapper

How to import Bootstrap icons with AssetMapper in Symfony 6.4/7.0?

I have already imported Bootstrap CSS + JS and it works. For icons I tried `symfony console importmap:require bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css` found on jsDeliver, but it fails:

> Unable to find the latest version for package "bootstrap-icons" - try specifying the version manually.

So I tried 1.11.0 (version from the Bootstrap website) but I get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Well it works without version mentioned: `symfony console importmap:require bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css` so that gets the latest version.

Comment: I appreciated that you share your answer! Could you please accept your own answer?